# How to call a REST endpoint when a post is published?

Tags: hooks, publish, rest-api

I need to make WordPress call a specific REST endpoint when a new post is published, passing the most important post data via JSON.

I found a plugin, HookPress, that apparently did just that by letting you configure webhooks for various events. Unfortunately it has not been updated in over 2 years and does not work with recent versions of Wordpress (>4.6).

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: Hi. I don't quite understand what you are looking for. Where should the data be passed to? Can you add a simple example please?

Comment: I have a webapp that exposes a REST API. I need Wordpress to call such API when a new post is published and send the relevant information about said post (post title, post body, post permalink, etc).
Basically, I need the exact same behaviour that was offered by the HookPress plugin.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to write a new plugin. You can either add the code to your theme's `functions.php` file, or create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

To wrap your data in a JSON format, you can use the `json_encode` function. Hook into the post when it's published, and send the data. In the following function, i will send the post's title, excerpt and featured image URL to the endpoint.

```
add_action('publish_post', 'call_the_endpoint',10,2);
function call_the_endpoint($post_id, $post){
    // Define an empty array
    $data = array();
    // Store the title into the array
    $data['title'] = get_the_title();
    // If there is a post thumbnail, get the link
    if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
        $data['thumbnail'] = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(),'thumbnail' );
    }
    // Get the excerpt and save it into the array
    $data['excerpt'] = get_the_excerpt();
    // Encode the data to be sent
    $json_data = json_encode($data);
    // Initiate the cURL
    $url = curl_init('YOUR API URL HERE');
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($url, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
        'Content-Length: ' . strlen($json_data))
    );
    // The results of our request, to use later if we want.
    $result = curl_exec($url);
}
```

It would be possible to write an accurate answer if you could provide more information about your API and how you interact with it. However this was a simple example for you to know how to use the `publish_post` hook to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: @Marcello You're welcome! Glad it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a post status transition hook. In this case, it sounds like {status}_{post_type} may be the most fitting. Assuming you're talking about Posts:

```
<?php
/* Plugin Name: Publish to REST
Description: Whenever a Post is published, WP will call a REST endpoint.
*/
add_action('publish_post', 'wpse_send_rest_data', 10, 2);
function wpse_send_rest_data($ID, $post) {
    // Add your code to call the REST endpoint here.
    // The $post object is available so you can send post details.
    // Example: $post->post_title will give you the title.
    // $post->post_excerpt will give you an excerpt.
    // get_permalink($post) will give you the permalink.
}
?>
```

In this case, any time a post of type "Post" transitions to "Publish" status (could be brand-new, or an update, or a scheduled post) your custom function will be executed. This type of code is probably most suited to a custom plugin, since presumably even if you change the theme at some point you'll still want to make your custom REST call.

Comment: So, there really is no alternative to writing a new plugin from scratch? Where do I write the code from your example? Could you please add to your example the code to make a POST HTTP request and send some JSON data? That would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible a plugin exists, but it's pretty likely you'll need to create your own plugin. Save the example code as publish-to-rest.php, upload it into /wp-content/plugins/publish-to-rest/ and activate it. Research your particular API, find out what it takes to make the call, try a few things out, and then if you're stuck on a specific error you can create a new WPSE question. You won't find someone to write it all for free, especially since we don't know what API you're trying to call.