# Easiest way to call an External rest API?

Tags: api

I am currently attempting to make a simple GET call on an external API and then to populate the page with the response, no matter I search I cannot seem to find a clear or understandable answer as how to do this or if it is even possible.

Edit:

I have found an answer, however I feel that I should expand on what I wanted as I feel that Mark Kaplun was right. What I wanted to be able to do was make an external API call to GET a response from my own backend service (dreamfactory in this case). The issue that arose, largely due to my unfamiliarity with WordPress, was that I could not find a way to send off an api call. What it transpired the issue was that I attempted to make the api call inside the page and not inside the "Functions.php" page that I should of done, calling a short-code inside the page editor to activate it.

Comment: maybe you should start ny editing the question and explaining better what is it that you want to do

Comment: [This](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/269691/94498) answer of mine might be the one that you are looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mark is right, without knowing more, this is a hard question to answer.  This is a general guide though (not written by me) that I've used for my projects in the past.

https://yoast.com/wordpress-http-api/

It should get you started and then if you have other questions, please let us know.

Comment: It turns out a general guide was what was needed, as explained in the edit I was using incorrect code styles in the wrong area.

Comment: Great news!  Let me know if anything else comes up.

Comment: Yoast page has been deleted